# Powershell : form not displaying when one is called after the one another

Tags: forms, powershell, showdialog

I am beginner so the question might be silly.
I have a code for a multi-select list box. when I run it, it goes OK.I have also another function for selecting files, which works independently fine too.

However, when I do combine the 2, (first the file chooser then the list box), the list box is showing blank, and the item list is appearing when I put my mouse on them. When I use it in a longer code, powershell get frozen.

Does anyone can give me a hint on why this is happening and how to solve it?
Thanks a lot

Code for the file chooser:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

function Read-OpenFileDialog([string]$WindowTitle, [string]$InitialDirectory, [string]$Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*", [switch]$AllowMultiSelect) 
         {     
          $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog     
          $openFileDialog.Title = $WindowTitle     
          if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($InitialDirectory)) { $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory } 
          $openFileDialog.Filter = $Filter    
          if ($AllowMultiSelect) { $openFileDialog.MultiSelect = $true }     
          $openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true    
          # Without this line the ShowDialog() function may hang depending on system configuration and running from console vs. ISE.     
          $openFileDialog.ShowDialog() > $null    
          if ($AllowMultiSelect) { return $openFileDialog.Filenames } else { return $openFileDialog.Filename }
          $openFileDialog.Close()
          } 
$filePath = Read-OpenFileDialog -WindowTitle "Select the file" -InitialDirectory '~' -Filter "Project Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
```

code for the item list box:

```
$x = @()
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" 
if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($InitialDirectory)) { $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory } 

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {
        foreach ($objItem in $objListbox.SelectedItems)
            {$x += $objItem}
            $objForm.Close()
    }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"

$OKButton.Add_Click(
   {
        foreach ($objItem in $objListbox.SelectedItems)
            {$x += $objItem}
        $objForm.Close()
   })

$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please make a selection from the list below:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox 
$objListbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 

$objListbox.SelectionMode = "MultiExtended"

[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("Item 1")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("Item 2")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("Item 3")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("Item 4")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("Item 5")

$objListbox.Height = 70
$objForm.Controls.Add($objListbox) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x
```

Comment: Does the code work in ISE and fail in powershell.exe ?

Comment: Yes, this is the case.
In addition, when I run the code only with one of these functions, and then run the code with the two functions, then everything is all right. The problem appears only when I am running the code with the 2 functions directly.

Comment: Create a shortcut with this target : `powershell.exe -sta -file pathtofile.ps1`. If this works, I'll make an answer out of it with an explanation (even if I don't fully understand the concept of threads ... ^^)

Comment: Hello Sodawillow
I did not fully understood what you asked me to do. However, I found a solution to my problem by adding prior to these two funciton a pop up window, that the user should click 'ok'. Then everything is running fine without problem. I guess this is not a proper solution, but I think I will go with it.

Comment: My advice was to combine the 2 in a script you would call with the shortcut above. If you ever try it, tell me if it worked : )